# Composition relation using abstract classes-Java

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract, composition

I have a has a relationship between 2 classes: one is abstract class **Region** and the other is class **KenKen**. I have an ArrayList of type Region in class KenKen. How can I access the method **addValue** in Region class?

The classes are as follows:

Kenken:

```
public class KenKen {

private ArrayList<Region> regions;

public KenKen(String filename)throws FileNotFoundException{

  //constructor
  regions = new ArrayList<Region>();
  //regions.addValue(0);//   

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{


       KenKen kenken1 = new KenKen("input.1.txt");


  }

}
```

Region:

```
public abstract class Region{

private int number = 0;
protected int target = 0;
protected ArrayList<Integer> values;

   public Region(int number , int target){

      this.number = number;
      this.target = target;

      //constructor
      values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   }

   public void addValue(int val){

   }
   public abstract boolean verify();

   public String toString(){


   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a member of an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) you should use [`get(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)):

> Returns the element at the specified position in this list.

So:

```
regions.get(index).addValue(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get()` method to reach region objects in the list.

`regions.get(0).addValue(0);`

Answer (score 1):

regions is an ArrayList of Regions, you should do something like

```
    regions.get(index).addValue(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a public method in the KenKen class to acces the region list.

```
public List<Region> getRegions() {
    return regions;
}
```

and then you can call addValue()

```
getRegions().get(index).addValue(value);
```